# Выбор определенной строки из БД Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой:

1. Создаем базу данных с некоторыми пунктами такими как "number"(вместо id строки), "apn", "ip", и т.д.
2. Нужно сделать так, когда вводишь в EditText номер (number) по нажатию кнопки SMS отправлялась СМС с данными из строки которой ранее был присвоен введенный номер.

   ```
           case R.id.smssend:
               Cursor cd = db.query("mytable", null, number, null, null, null, null);
               if (cd.moveToPosition(inumber)) {
                   int spin1ColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("spin1");
                   int spin2ColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("spin2");
                   int ip1ColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("ip1");
                   int socket1ColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("socket1");
                   int ip2ColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("ip2");
                   int socket2ColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("socket2");
                   int apnColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("apn");
                   int gprsColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("gprs");
                   int namegprsColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("namegprs");
                   int passgprsColIndex = cd.getColumnIndex("passgprs");

                   sendSmsMessage("+380676711761", cd.getString(spin1ColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(spin2ColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(ip1ColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(socket1ColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(ip2ColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(socket2ColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(apnColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(gprsColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(namegprsColIndex) + "*"
                           + cd.getString(passgprsColIndex));
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
               else {
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Такого об'єкту не знайдено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   toast.show();
               }
               break;
   ```

   UPD Вот проблема с использованием movetoposition (там нужно int значение) но мне надо чтобы его можна было вводить в Edittext

UPD: вот еще что нашел, с помощью этого у меня получилось искать нужное число, но как это к моей программе применить... сижу разбираюсь
Взято из [урока](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/76-urok-36-sqlite-podrobnee-pro-metod-query-uslovie-sortirovka-gruppirovka.html)

```
case R.id.btnPeople:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Население больше " + sPeople + " ---");
            selection = "people = ?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] { sPeople };
            c = db.query("mytable", null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
            break;
```

Comment: Без поля _id в БД ,стандартные классы android , связанные с обработкой данных из БД , будут работать некорректно или вовсе работать не будут

Comment: Пожалуйста, уберите весь лишний код, оставив только проблемные места относящиеся к вопросу.

Comment: Да кстати, если if (cd.moveToPosition(inumber)) заменить на if (cd.moveToFirst()) - все нормально, смс отсылает... но естественно первой записи в БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено полностью:

```
//--------------------------------------SMS SEND Button---------------------------------
        case R.id.smssend:
            selection = "number = ?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] { number };
            c = db.query("mytable", null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int spin1ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("spin1");
                int spin2ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("spin2");
                int ip1ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("ip1");
                int socket1ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("socket1");
                int ip2ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("ip2");
                int socket2ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("socket2");
                int apnColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("apn");
                int gprsColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("gprs");
                int namegprsColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("namegprs");
                int passgprsColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("passgprs");

                sendSmsMessage("+380676711761", c.getString(spin1ColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(spin2ColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(ip1ColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(socket1ColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(ip2ColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(socket2ColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(apnColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(gprsColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(namegprsColIndex) + "*"
                        + c.getString(passgprsColIndex));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Такого об'єкту не знайдено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно превратить число, введенное в текстовое поле в int - переменную, то достаточно выполнить следующее:

```
int inumber = Integer.parseInt(edNumber.getText().toString());
```

Comment: вышло, но оно отсылает по номеру строки, а можно ли сделать так, чтобы номер строки можно было самому изменять? Возникла идея - смотреть в какой строке есть нужное значение number, после чего записать в переменную значение с getPosition, и потом делать moveToPosition

Comment: А смотреть где? Напрямую в базе или у Вас есть некий ListView, выводящий данные базы для обозрения?

Comment: напрямую в базе, т.к. там будет несколько тысяч записей